# Kivy , Buildozer install on non connected devices

Tags: kivy, buildozer

I am currently able to create some simple android apk's using kivy/ buildozer, but the only way I have been able to work out how  get them onto my phone for testing is via the backward step of copying the .apk into google drives, and then opening/ installing the same .apk via accessing google drives on my phone.

According to the documentation on https://buildozer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html, its possible to pass the .apk directly to your device or onto a non connected device via the *serve* command.

Has anyone got the *buildozer serve* command to work at all?  When I try, I just get stuck on the following message

Serving via HTTP at port 8000

Press Ctrl+c to quit serving.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After starting the server via buildozer, you have to open a browser on your phone and type the address of the server in the address bar. If your ip for your pc is `192.168.1.215` then you would type

```
192.168.1.215:8000
```

into the browser. If you are running `Linux` on your pc, you can get your ip address by running:

```
ifconfig
```